# Swift 2.2. Save dictionary to plist

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift2

I have these two functions. First, readPlaylist() which seem to work fine. If the plist is already saved in DocumentDirectory, it is returned from there or else it will be copied to the path and then returned.

The function savePlaylist(dict: NSMutableDictionary) takes a NSMutableDictionary and prints it out fine. This function uses same path-code as readPlaylist(), so the path should be right.
Then i try to write the dict to the url. i get no errors but writeToUrl returns false and when i print out resultDictionary i get the original plist copied to the DocumentDirectory, no changes made.

I also tried the “old way” and used writeToFile, but with same result.

The dict contains string keys with array values that holds custom object

Why can’t i save my dict to the plist?

The code:

```
 func readPlaylist() -> NSMutableDictionary  {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as NSString
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths as String).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Playlists.plist")


    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    //check if file exists
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path.path!){
        let plistPathInBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Playlists", ofType: "plist") as String!
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(plistPathInBundle, toPath: path.path!)
        }catch{
            print("Error occurred while copying file to document \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Playlists.plist already exits at path.")
    }
    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfURL: path)
    print("Loaded Playlists.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")

    return resultDictionary!

}

func savePlaylist(dict: NSMutableDictionary) {

    print("mydict --> \(dict.description)")

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as NSString
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths as String).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Playlists.plist")

    print("test if true or false: \(dict.writeToURL(path, atomically: true))")

    dict.writeToURL(path, atomically: true)


    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfURL: path)
    print("Saved Playlists.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")

}
```

Playlist.plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>QuePlayer</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Basically in Swift it's always recommended to use native Swift types. Especially the mutable Foundation types NSMutableArray/-Dictionary are not related at all to the Swift counterparts and can cause errors. To serialize a dictionary there is a dedicated class `NSPropertyListSerialization` which provides better error handling.

Comment: PS: what is *custom object*? Property list files support only `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, and `Array` / `Dictionary` containing the 4 basic  types.

Comment: My object look like this. It should be serializable. But can't i use custom objects like this in a property list?
`class Music: NSObject {
    
    var song : String!
    var albumTitle : String!
    var artist : String!    
    init(song: String, albumTitle: String, artist: String) {
        super.init()
        self.song = song
        self.albumTitle = albumTitle
        self.artist = artist
    }


}
`

Comment: Custom objects must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, then they can be serialized with `NSArchiver` to `NSData` objects.